# Substring select string between two characters

Tags: sql-server

The following code

```
declare @text VARCHAR(MAX) 
set @text='[Dim Company].[Company].[23]'
SELECT SUBSTRING(@Text, CHARINDEX('[Dim Company].[Company].[', @Text)
, CHARINDEX(']',@text) - CHARINDEX('[Dim Company].[Company].[', @Text) + Len(']'))
```

Returns `[Dim Company]`.  I was expecting it to return the integer between the last `[]` -- in this case `23`.  How can I get the desired field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know it's always last, why not `REVERSE` the string, find the value between the *first* pair of brackets, then `REVERSE` that result?

Much easier than nesting `CHARINDEX` calls.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you `23]`

```
SELECT RIGHT(@text, CHARINDEX('[',REVERSE(@text))-1)
```

This will give you `23`

```
SET @tmp = RIGHT(@text, CHARINDEX('[',REVERSE(@text))-1)
SET @tmp = LEFT(@tmp, LEN(tmp)-1)
```

fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/36013

Answer (score -1):

I agree with mwigdahl, this is bad way of doing things, but this is the answer you seek:

```
declare @text VARCHAR(MAX) 
set @text='[Dim Company].[Company].[23]'
SELECT SUBSTRING(@Text, 
                 LEN('[Dim Company].[Company].[')+1,
                 LEN(@text)-LEN('[Dim Company].[Company].[')-1)
```

A better approach is to use the `PARSENAME()` function.  The function's purpose is actually to parse an object name, such as `server.schema.table`, but since your string looks just like that, we can hijack the function.  It's far more efficient, and cleaner than `charindex`/`substring`.

```
declare @text varchar(max), @p1 varchar(max), @p2 varchar(max), @p3 varchar(max)
set @text='[Dim Company].[Company].[23]'                 
set @p1 = PARSENAME(@text, 3)
set @p2 = PARSENAME(@text, 2)
set @p3 = PARSENAME(@text, 1)

select @p1, @p2, @p3
```

Comment: Problem says information between last [] -- does not say how many are before.  If it said 3rd [] parsename might be an ok hack.

Comment: I suppose you're right.  He hard coded the charindex, so I assumed it would always be 3 sets, and the first 2 were static.